# Linking pull requests to the workitems from the TFS database

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015, pull-request

We use custom queries (against TFS databases: Tfs_DefaultCollection and Tfs_Warehouse) to check if all changesets have a workitem linked to it. We use the FactWorkItemChangeset table from the Tfs_Warehouse database.
Currently we are migrating to TFS Git and we want to update our custom queries to check if all the pull requests have a workitem linked to it. 
For example:
Git pull request and its workitem[image]
We don't know where in the Tfs_Warehouse or in the Tfs_Defaultcollection database the pull request is linked to the workitem. Does anyone know where this link is stored?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find the related table, however you can use the REST API to check if all the pull requests have a workitem linked to it. Please see [Get Pull Requests By Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests%20by%20project?view=vsts-rest-4.1) and [Pull Request Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pull%20request%20work%20items/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) for details.

For example, below PowerShell script will retrieve all the Pull Requests from a specific project and list the linked work items for each of them, also output the Pull Requests which have no linked work items to a `*.csv` file (`"D:\temp\1030.csv"` in below sample).

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://172.17.16.163:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection", 
   [string]$project = "GitTest",
   [string]$user = "Domain\user",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get pull request list for a specific project
$prsurl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/git/pullrequests?api-version=2.0"
$prs = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $prsurl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
$prurls = $prs.value.url

#Get the associated work items to PRs
Clear-Host

foreach ($prurl in $prurls)
{
$baseurl = "$prurl/workitems"

$prwis = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseurl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

write-host "Pull Reuquest:" $prurl

write-host "Count of Associated Work Items:"$prwis.count 
 foreach ($prwi in $prwis.value )
  {
   Write-Host "Associated workitem:"$prwi.id - $prwi.url
  }
  write-host `n

if ($prwis.count -lt 1)
 {
  #Write-host $prurl
  # Output the Pull Requests which have no work items associated:
  $prurl | Add-Content "D:\temp\1030.csv"  
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for your answer! What we were looking for is the link in de tfs_defaultcollection database. But with the api and the sql server profiler we finally found the answer:  the link between a workitem and a pull request is stored in the [WorkItemFiles] table in the tfs_Default database!

Answer (score 0):

We finally found the link in de Tfs_DefaultCollection.WorkItemFiles! For example:                                                          select *
from [dbo].[WorkItemFiles]
where FilePath = 'vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/4f39e226-6f44-4e56-a216-f45969d8147d%2fab3368e0-56ef-468f-8e14-43065c433a21%2f2619'

This yields this result:
ID        427787
FilePath  vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/4f39e226-6f44-4e56-a216-f45969d8147d%2fab3368e0-56ef-468f-8e14-43065c433a21%2f2619

The ID column contains the workitem id and the FilePath 2 hashes (separated by '%ef') and finally the pull request id. In this example workitem 427787 is linked to pull request 2619.