# get pull request information for a workItem in DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, wiql

I wanted to know the status of the pull request associated with a work item on the board. If possible able to filter on status.

Or

At minimum Is it possible to get the pull request details with WIQL.

Answer (score 0):

> get pull request information for a workItem in DevOps API

If you want to get the state of the workitem, which associated with the PR, you could use the REST API [Pull Requests - Get Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=5.1
```

Then we could get the pull request details, which including following response body:

```
"workItems": {
    "href": "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_apis/git/repositories/0f1bc369-c105-435d-a443-9c933f9bd98f/pullRequests/112/workitems"
},
```

Next, we just get the `href` from above response body, we could get the workitem details:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_apis/git/repositories/0f1bc369-c105-435d-a443-9c933f9bd98f/pullRequests/112/workitems
```

The response body:

```
"value": [
    {
        "id": "145",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_apis/wit/workItems/145"
    }
```

So, we get the workitem ID, then we use the REST API [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the status of workitem:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. But I have a sprint of items and want to know the status of the associated pull request details for all the items. If I use the above method I have to go through all the thousands of pull requests and search for my work Item( thousands of HTTP requests). so I want to know all the pull requests associated with my work-item.

Comment: @Pavank, If you have thousands of pull requests, you can try to write the powershell scripts to traverse all the pull requests and traverse all the workitems in the PR. Like:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043203/linking-pull-requests-to-the-workitems-from-the-tfs-database/53057813#53057813. But, if you want use WIQL to get the workitem, then get the PRs, I am afraid you could not achieve it, because we could not get the links by WIQL.